# View got Overlapped by List Items in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, list, swiftui

I created a view that animate and put it on the `index 0` of List with `zindex(1)` so its keep it self on front all the time and another view for all other index's with `zindex(-1)`...

[image]

its work fine for first time but when scroll the list or navigate to detail of list item the second view with zindex(-1) overlap the first view ...

[image]

above image show how it suppose to work all the time ...

[image]

but this is what happen when after came back from detail of some specific index item  ... its cover the first View which have `zindex(1)` ...

[image]

And this is what happened when scroll the list ... all the other views overlap the first view ...

Here is the code

```
        NavigationView{
                
                List(0 ..< 10) { item in
                    if (item == 0) {
                        Spacer()
                         TasiMarketCard()
                            .padding(.top)
                            .zIndex(1)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                self.isBlur.toggle()
                        }
                        
                    }else {
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text("1")){
                         HomeItem()
                            .zIndex(-1)
                        }
                    }
                    }
                .navigationBarTitle("Home")
                .blur(radius: self.isBlur ? 10 : 0)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just by code reading... try zIndex in different place

```
NavigationLink(destination: Text("1")){
   HomeItem()
}.zIndex(-1)      // << here !!
```

Comment: i did ... but nothing changed ... even i noticed that `zindex()` have zero impact on list views ... removing `zindex()` also have same behaviour as before...